# How autoloader works in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, package, composer-php, autoloader

I am just trying to create a package for packagist, a zend framework 2 user authentication module, https://packagist.org/packages/tahmina8765/zf2auth

When I keep this zf2auth folder in my modules folder, it works. But when I download it with composer, it downloaded in vendor/tahmina8765/zf2auth.
In this folder, it does not work. I mean, I have added this module in application.config.php -

```
'modules' => array(
    ...
    'Zf2auth'
),
```

but here it does not work. If I keep it on step ahead, ie. vendor/zf2auth it works again.

How can I make it workable in vendor/tahmina8765/zf2auth folder?

Comment: see @guessimtoolate post for valid solution. Update your package and run composer update to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a problem with the `composer.json` file in your module. It says:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Zf2auth": "./"
    }
}
```

and looking at the directory structure it should be:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Zf2auth\\": "src"
    }
}
```

It works in your `./modules/` dir because of the `getAutoloaderConfig` you have in your module class -- that's done by ZF2. When you download the module through composer however, the autoloading (probably) get's done by composer and the autoload (invalid) definition in your composer manifest is used. You might also want to run composers `dump` command afterwords, to refresh the autoloading classes.

Comment: hi, guessimtoolate, thank oyu for ur solution, adter generating autoload_classpam files and update the packages, it is working. But would you please help me to understand, why '\\' should bee added with Zf2auth?

Comment: Not entirely sure if it's neccessary, but it's a nice way to underscore the fact that is the base dir for a namespace (hence \ at the end). Since it's JSON, and backslashes are used to escape chars in it, the backslash needs to be escaped as well.